# Does this sudden 500 mean my script is being throttled?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, resource-throttling

I have a script whose job it is to POST about 20,000 pdfs (average size 200k) to a SharePoint list, while populating a couple of text and date columns. The script runs on a schedule, every 5 minutes. I'm using the REST api. I'm not including a UserAgent.

It started running this morning and was working fine, until after sending through about 5000 pdfs (5003 to be precise) over the course of a few hours it started getting a 500 back. Is this some kind of throttling? If it were being throttled I would expect something like a 429. Of course I will try again tomorrow, but in the meantime how do I go about investigating this?

Preparing a post:

```
private ServiceResponse Export(SourceRecord sourceRecord, Document sourceDocument) throws Exception {
        String url = null;
        Map<String,String> headers = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
        
        // wrapper for the profile. Exposes the SharePoint-related values on the Settings page
        com.aso.sp.Settings spSettings = new com.aso.sp.Settings(_profile);
        
        // url
        sb
        .append("https://")
        .append(spSettings.getTargetDomain() )
        .append("/sites/")
        .append( spSettings.getTargetSite() )
        .append("/").append( spSettings.getTargetAPIPath() )
        .append("/GetByTitle('").append(spSettings.getTargetList()).append("')/items");
        url = sb.toString();
        
        // build payload
        Date d = sourceRecord.getTimeReceived();
        sb.setLength(0);
        sb
            .append("{")
            .append("\"Title\":\"").append( sourceRecord.getTitle() ).append("\",")
            .append("\"SenderFax\":\"").append( sourceRecord.getSenderFax() ).append("\",")
            .append("\"SenderState\":\"").append( sourceRecord.getState() ).append("\",")
            .append("\"SenderStoreNumber\":\"").append( sourceRecord.getStoreNumber() ).append("\",")
            .append("\"Received\"").append(":\"").append( sdf.format(d) ).append("\"")
            .append("}");
        String payload = sb.toString();
        
        // headers
        headers = new HashMap<String,String>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
        headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
        headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + spSettings.getToken());
        headers.put("User-Agent", spSettings.getUserAgent());
        
        ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
        ServiceResponse response = client.Post(url, headers, payload);
        
        // if 201, attach the pdf
        if(response.getCode() == 201) {
            
            // parse out id here
            int id = ...;
            attachFiles(id, sourceDocument);
        }
        
        return response;
    }
```

The post:

```
public ServiceResponse Post(String url, Map<String,String> headers, String body) throws ... {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        
        try {
            URL urlObj = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            
            // bearer token is in here
            for(String k:headers.keySet()) {
                connection.setRequestProperty(k, headers.get(k));
            }
            
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            
            OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream(); 
            byte[] input = body.getBytes();
            os.write(input, 0, input.length);
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            
            // reponse logging snipped
            
            BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()) );
            String inputLine;
            sb.setLength(0);
            while ((inputLine = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(inputLine);
            }
            inputReader.close();
            String responseBody = sb.toString();
                
            return new ServiceResponse(responseCode, responseBody);
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            // snip
        } catch(Exception e) {
            // snip
        } 
        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both 429 and 503 are related to the throttling. The best practice is to catch these error codes and then re-try your query in 1,2,4,8,16,32 seconds. Basically, you keep trying your query, and if it fails, you double the wait time.

Comment: Denis, I'm getting a 500, not 503. I can post at any rate, but when there are 5000 records in the list I will get a 500, and any further attempt will get a 500, no matter how long a delay I introduce. If I delete one record, I can send one more, and then it will fail again. But I can send records from Postman, and all these will get a 201. The only thing I haven't tried is to register an app and send the app info in a header. (But then, I'm not writing an app, this is just a one-time migration script.)

Comment: Can you post a sample of your code?

Comment: Sure, added code above. I get a 500 back if there are >=5000 rows in the list, every time, regardless of how long I wait before sending another. There is nothing unusual in the response headers (no Retry-After etc) up to that point. I checked this also by invoking the code against random records, to make sure the list wasn't choking on a particular row.

Comment: Denis, I find that the exception is not actually happening on my POST, but on the precautionary GET I do beforehand to check if the endpoint already has a matchng record. This returns a 500 if the row count exceeds 5000, and the message is "The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold". This makes some sense, becuase I suppose it has to render the result from some view, or a default view if I did not include any. Still, I wonder if there's a way around this. I don't like to just drop a row in there w/o checking for a duplicate.

Comment: In this case, you need to make sure that in the list settings > column indexes > you create all indexes that you mention in your GET query. For example, you can create indexes for these columns: Title, SenderFax, SenderState, SenderStoreNumber, Received